# How can I replace a part of an image using ffmpeg

Tags: image, ffmpeg

I have an image. I want to replace a part (I have coordinate of this part) of this image with other image. Is there any command available in ffmpeg to replace this part with given coordinates or is there any other option?

Comment: I think best option is imagemagick

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can use the [`overlay`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay) video filter in ffmpeg. In this example the overlay will be placed 160 pixels to the right on the *x* axis and 120 pixels down on the *y* axis:

```
ffmpeg -i img0.png -i img1.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=160:120" \
-frames:v 1 out.png
```

You can also use the width and height of either the background image or the foreground image as values for *x* and *y*.

From the [`overlay` documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay):

> `main_w, W`
>   `main_h, H`
>   main input width and height
>
> `overlay_w, w`
>   `overlay_h, h`
>   overlay input width and height

So if my background image is 320x240, and my foreground image is 160x120, and I wanted the foreground image to be in the bottom left:

```
ffmpeg -i img0.png -i img1.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=0:overlay_w" \
-frames:v 1 out.png
```